# Get category collection from specific store

Tags: catalog, category

With flat tables turned off, how can I get a category collection from a specific store view ?

I have tried the following:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(3);
```

But it only returns the collection for the default store?

What is not correct with my example?

Comment: : can i get the working code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of store filter, try with root category filter.

```
$rootcatID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $rootcatID))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$productCollection->load();
```

Comment: As mentioned on a previous answer, calling `load` directly on a collection is not desirable.

Comment: Why this answer accepted as correct? Question is about category collection, not product mentioned here.

Comment: @Marty: Did this answer really solve your questions? You might want to edit the question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 24):

In Magento store has relationship with only root category and all categories belong to this root category are belong to particular store. To load store categories you should use store root category id, and you can load all categories of this root. See these:

```
    $rootId     = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('path', array('like'=> "1/$rootId/%"));

    echo $categories->count();
```

Comment: this should be accepted

Comment: this works well but left me a question. What's the point of magento having setStore if it doesn't automatically filter collection by its root category ID for that current store?

Answer (score 4):

**In Magento 1.9**

```
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
            

            $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"))
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

                foreach ($categories as $categorie)
                {
                    $catid = $categorie->getId();                   
                    $catname = $categorie->getName();
                    $catp = $categorie->getParentId();
                }
```

Comment: so what is causing the correct filter here? Is t the store specific rootCategoryId  || is it ->setStoreId($storeId) in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help somebody, but with a little digging and testing i came up with the following:

```
$catCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->setStoreId(9) //where 9 should be your store id
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
```