# Programmatically recursively enable all categories

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I would like to know how I can loop through recursively the entire category structure and enable every category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
 require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
 umask(0);
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);


$_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 0);

    foreach ($_categories as $_category){
       // if you have any issue then you many need to load the 
       // $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
       $_category->setIsActive(1);
       $_category->save();
    }
```

If you have multiple stores or categories root see [Get category collection from specific store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9411/get-category-collection-from-specific-store)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following script:

```
<?php

define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$tree     = $category->getTreeModel();
$tree->load();

$ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();

// Activate the categories
foreach ($ids as $_id) {

    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_id);

    $_category->setIsActive(1);
    $_category->save();
    echo "Enabled " . $_id . "\n";

}

?>
```