# Category grid doesn't show categories on homepage

Tags: category, grid

I have multiple stores in my Magento. For each store I have created a home page in `CMS > Pages > Manage pages`. At the design tab I use this layout update XML code:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home-categories" template="custom/category_grid.phtml" after="-"/>

<!--
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
</block>
-->
</reference>
```

The result of including this code in the layout update XML textarea is that each category will be displayed at the homepage. See screenshots below:

Here the categories are working:
(the `<ul>` tag is included in the html) 
[image]

Here the categories aren't working: (the `<ul>` tag is **not** included in the html)

[image]

The problem is that one store doesn't show the categories in the grid. I think that the solution to this problem lays somewhere else but I don't know where to look. Where can I look?

**Update**

The code of function getSelectSQL in "lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php"

```
function getSelectSql($stringMode = false)
    {
        if ($stringMode) {
            return $this->_select->__toString();
        }
        return $this->_select;
    }
```

Comment: The `<!-- [...] -->` means that it is inactive. So including this code shouldn't result in a grid. My guess is that the grid is coming from somewhere else

Comment: @Sander please see my code update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using block type `catalog/product_new`, but you are outputting with template `category_grid`. According to your question it sounds like you are trying output category collection. But in your block definition in section type you are trying to get **PRODUCT COLLECTION**.

Please clarify your goal. What do you need to output? Categories or products?

And i'd like to draw your attention on method `_getProductCollection()`. It has following rows:

```
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
```

If you have no products, created during this period - you'll get empty result.

Comment: I can't even imagine what do you want to output. Categories have tree structure. To get categories collection - use your own category collection. Here are some examples how to get it: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9411/get-category-collection-from-specific-store And most probably you know what to output, as you have some custom/category_grid template

Comment: You mean that the described code is working properly on one store. Ok, show please $collection->getSelectSQL(1) before return. And also show the template code

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: I know the code of getSelectSQL method.... I looked for result of your collection.

Comment: I found the solution which was to add the category id of the webshop in category_grid.phtml